# Use Throttling to restrict the number of times a certain request can be made globally

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, throttling

I am using Django Throttling, and want to add a behavior that will throttle users from calling a certain request more than X times in rate - globally.

Using AnonRateThrottle or UserRateThrottle is not good enough for me, because it checks the number of times that a certain User or IP address made the request. I want to limit the global calls to a certain api_view, no matter who made the request.

For example, if the rate is 1/min and user X made a request, than every other user will be throttled for the next minute.

EDIT:
Thanks to Kaushal's answer below, I found a way to make this work by adding:

```
def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
    return request.method + request.get_full_path()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply throttle globally for view you can use same key.
here idea is use same key per view. that mean for all request it'll use same key to get request count data

```
from rest_framework import throttling

class MyViewRateThrottle(throttling.SimpleRateThrottle):
    rate = '3/m'

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        return view.__class__.__name__
```

this will throttle per view. same as you're looking for

Comment: It looks promising, but when I use your solution I get an error:
`*** AttributeError: 'wrapper' object has no attribute '__name__'`. I have tried to use `view.get_view_name()` but it returns the string 'Wrapper' and not the view name

Comment: I guess it should only work with Class-Based-Views or also with Function-Based-Views?
There is the `request.get_full_path()` which returns the url of that Function Based View. I think it should work fine concatenating that with `request.method`.

Comment: answer has been edited. it should work for all. by looking at decorator code which used in function based view it convert func. into class. so above code would work for both.

Comment: It still returns the string "wrapper" which will throttle all function based views globally and not a specific function based view

Answer (score 0):

Here I created Throttling for specific user

#### throttling.py

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class RockyRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
 scope = 'rocky'
```

#### settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES':{
        'anon': '2/day',     # For Anonymous user
        'user': '5/hour',    # For Registred user
        'rocky': '3/minute'  # For register but specific user
    }
}
```

#### views.py

```
from rest_framework.throttling import AnonRateThrottle, UserRateThrottle
from api.throttling import RockyRateThrottle


class StudentModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Student.objects.all()
  serializer_class = StudentSerializer
  authentication_classes=[SessionAuthentication]
  permission_classes=[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
  #  throttle_classes = [AnonRateThrottle, UserRateThrottle]
  throttle_classes = [AnonRateThrottle, RockyRateThrottle] # this is working for 'anon' and 'Rocky'
```

Comment: I think rate would be like 2/d, 5/d & so on

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

Comment: Thanks.
First, it doesn't answer my question. I don't want to throttle a specific user.
The basic throttling throttles BY USER. I want To throttle ALL USERS. I want to limit a request for 5/hour for all users in a way that the request will not happen more than 5 times OVERALL.

Second, I don't understand how you example only limits a specific user rocky. For what I understand it will throttle EVERY user (authorized or anonimous). where does the "# For register but specific user" applied?

Comment: I already add for every authenticated user code and anon user which is commented in views.py

Comment: Here i take total three scenario first for anon, second is authorised user and third one for authorised but specific user